# Proof that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} d_{i} \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \min\{d_{i},k\}$ in a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $G$ be a simple graph with degree sequence $(d_{1},\dots,d_{n})$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} d_{i} \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \min\{d_{i},k\}.$$

Proof:

Consider a subset $U$, with cardinality $k$, of vertices, such that edges that have at least one vertex within $U$ are also in $U$.

Then for each vertex within $U$, it has some edges connecting in $U$ and some connecting to elements outside of $U$ (i.e. edges that have only one end in $U$). The sum of the degrees of the vertices of $U$ will be the sum of these two components for each element.

The first component cannot exceed $k(k-1)$, since at most each vertex can connect to $k-1$ other vertices within $U$.

Now we consider the second component. Counting the edges that have one vertex within $U$ is the same as summing over how many edges vertices outside of $U$ have incident with vertices within $U$.

For each vertex $v$ not in $U$, it can have at most $k$ edges to elements in $U$. Notice, though, the number of these edges also cannot exceed $d_{v}$, since this vertex only has that many edges. So this vertex is limited to $\min\{d_{v},k\}$ in terms of how many edges it can contribute to vertices within $U$.

Thus the sum cannot exceed $k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \min\{ d_{i},k\}$.

Is my proof rigorous and correct? I am suspect of how to make precise the notion of the contribution of vertices outside of $U$ to those within $U$.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is correct, but there are some minor issues:

- You can't take $U$ to be any subset of size $k$; it has to be specifically the subset corresponding to the vertices with degrees $d_1, \ldots, d_k$.
- What does "such that edges that have at least one vertex within $U$ are also in $U$" mean? I think that sentence can just be replaced by "Let $U$ be the subset of $k$ vertices with degrees $d_1, \ldots, d_k$."

Your wording for the second term (edges that have only one vertex in $U$) is fine.